# lattice orthogonal complement

Tags: lattices

Let $A\in \mathbb{Z}^{m\times n}$ ($m<n$) be a matrix with orthogonal rows. Further assume that the gcd of the coefficients in each row of $A$ is $1$.

Consider $\ker A\cap \mathbb{Z}^n = \{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n: Ax = 0\}$. How is $\det(\ker A\cap \mathbb{Z}^n)$ related to $A$? I tried a few small examples and it seems that $\det(\ker A\cap \mathbb{Z}^n)\cdot\det(A\mathbb{Z}^n) = \sqrt{\det(AA^T)}$. Is this generally true?

($\det(A\mathbb{Z}^n)$ is the determinant of $A\mathbb{Z}^n = \text{im} A \cap \mathbb{Z}^m$, an $m$-dimensional sublattice in $\mathbb{Z}^m$)

Comment: I think that this is about the notion of a dual lattice. see http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/DualLattice.pdf Maybe I will write some answer later

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102899/lattice-orthogonal-complement

Comment: There's a relationship proven for orthogonal complement's of lattices here https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/16/3/275/319724 . It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it may be related.

Answer (score 1):

This does not have much to do with integrality (except that you want the "maximal" lattice), and, while classical (probably in Siegel, though I can't find it right now), it is discussed in my paper Surface area and other measures of ellipsoids. (English summary) 
Adv. in Appl. Math.  39  (2007),  no. 4, 409–427 (also on arxiv.org) section 10 - it follows from fairly simple exterior algebra.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Like projecting fundamental parallelepiped onto different subspaces?